Hitron MoCA Adapter, FiOS Router (CR1000B), and Netgear RAX70 Router in AP Mode issue
As the title says, I have a Verizon CR1000B, a 4-way POE spec splitter (No terminator caps), a POE filter (I live in an apartment complex for reference), a Hitron HTEM5 MoCA adapter connected to a bedroom (which is then connected to an ethernet switch), and in another room via wired ethernet, a Netgear Nighthawk RAX70 router (the apartment made an ethernet passthrough from the closet where the Coax signal comes in to the living room). For a while I had this setup and it was working fine, but then two weeks ago I noticed that, my RAX70 wasn't set to AP mode, but just regular mode (I swear I toggled it since this isn't the first time I setup an AP on a network), but I never bothered to check after I got it up and running I guess. Anyways after I set it to AP mode, the MoCA adapter started acting up, it would disconnect / drop signal every couple of hours, but now it would disconnect almost every 5-10 minutes. I figured it's a loop error somewhere, but I can't figure out why or how. I set the RAX70 back to router mode, and I guess it works, but now the devices connected to it are on their own 10.0.0.x subnetwork and I prefer them not to be. It doesn't seem like the devices are conflicting for the same IP address either.
Also what makes it weird, is that when the desktop that is connected to the RAX70 via ethernet isn't on, the MoCA adapter doesn't drop (when the RAX70 was in AP mode). Not a big deal but would appreciate any thoughts or suggestions. Thanks!

So just clarifying, the path is CR1000B  HTEM5  switch  [(WAN port) RAX70 (LAN port)]  PC. Is that correct? So the PC was only on the same Ethernet LAN as the MoCA adapter when the RAX70 was in AP mode? I suppose it's possible that some kind of Ethernet frames the PC was sending—maybe multicast discovery protocols or something—was causing a buggy MoCA adapter to choke. Did you take any packet captures?

The HTEM5 is connected to the Coax of the CR1000B, whereas the RAX70 is connected via ethernet (RAX70 WAN) to the CR1000B (LAN 1 of 2). The RAX70 has a PC attached to it. The PC and HTEM5 work fine when the RAX70 is not in AP but in regular router mode. When the RAX70 is in AP mode it creates problems (But interestingly when the PC is not on in AP mode it works fine). Possible that the adapter is choking cause of specific frames but I didn't take any packet captures. I've used WireShark before but I admit I'm not well-versed. Any suggestions in terms of software to use?
